# Is it possible to register google registry docker containers with Kubernetes Spring Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Our team is using Kubernetes Spring Cloud Dataflow version 2.01, and it appears to require an explicit docker:// URL for docker containers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-kubernetes

We have been using google registry to register docker containers, Spring Cloud Dataflow throws an exception when trying to register docker containers from the google registry: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 58: gcr.io/....

It's a legit docker container, just not hosted by docker.  Is this a bug or is google registry unsupported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're missing is the configuration of private Docker registry in SCDF - see [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_private_docker_registry).

Once when you have that setup in SCDF/Skipper, you would be able to resolve images from any registry, as far as it is an implementation of Docker specs underneath. Google Container Registry should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sabby Anandan for sharing the docs link
From the link i understood that we need to update the configmap with the below code

```
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        skipper:
          server:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    imagePullSecret: mysecret
```

Not sure about the below lines

Once you have created the secret, you can use the imagePullSecret property to set the secret to use, as the following example shows:

```
deployer.<app>.kubernetes.imagePullSecret=mysecret
```

Comment: Let's say you had 2 apps in your stream: `stream create foo --definition "time | log"`; when deploying the `foo` stream, you would: `stream deploy foo --properties deployer.*.kubernetes.imagePullSecret=mysecret`, which will hint to SCDF/Skipper to resolve the `time` and `log` images from the private registry with the credential used for authentication. The wildcard `*` is used here to resolve images for _all_ apps in the definition. You can selectively pull an app from the private registry by specifying only the app name in the property. Eg: `deployer.time.kubernetes.imagePullSecret=mysecret`.

Comment: Followed the instructions from document and recreated configmap. Again i am getting the same error

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    imagePullSecret: gcr-json-key
                    limits:
                      memory: 1024Mi

Comment: Without any formatting, it is very hard to read the comment. Perhaps you could join the SCDF gitter channel and start a dialog there. You'd then be able to share the `skipper-config-rabbit.yaml` file in entirety, so that we can review the config settings.

Comment: Sure will login to gitter